# Reply для Comment AngularJS Error 404 not found HELP

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, api

у меня есть проблема: 
-Вывожу комментарии на страницу и их children элементы.
-Получаю id данного комментария.
-По клику на span{replay} - открывается форма.
-В поле textarea воодится текст и должен по клику на send отправлять данные на готовый back-end и дополнять массив данных json

Но последний пункт не работает - подскажите в чем проблема ??

вот мой код js

```
    $scope.addReply = function(_id){
        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "/comments/" + _id,
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            params : {
                'parent' : null,
                'content' : _id.content
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log(subComment);
            alert("Success REPLY!");
        }, function(response){
            alert("Failed REPLY!");
        }); 
    };

});
```

Вот мой HTML кусок этого элемента - >

```
 <li><a class="replytocomment" ng-click="openReplyArea = !openReplyArea" href=""><span><i class="fas fa-reply pl-3"></i></span>Replay</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                    <div class="text-area-reply" ng-show="openReplyArea">
                        <textarea name="post-reply" maxlength="255" id="post-reply" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message" ng-model="_id.content"></textarea>
                        <div class="col-lg-11 offset-lg-1">
                            <div class="button-post-reply text-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning text-muted reply" type="submit" id="reply" ng-click="addReply(item.id)">Reply</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Не понимаю, в чем ошибка... Может, я ошибаюсь с местом, куда я данные отправляю... Вот структура данных json на сервере[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните,что означает не работает,у вас ошибка какая то ,до баккенда запрос доходит ли нет ?

Comment: @vanyaAvchyan у меня error 404 not  found - я так понимаю, где то ошибка, связанная с тем, куда в json должны идти данные...

Comment: Ну это означает что вы URL неправильно указали. `http://frontend-test.pingbull.com/pages/paveligorevich55@icloud.com/comments/1` . Вот например я вручную передал единицу. Продебажте код в ручную, поймите почему запрос не доходит до вашего эkшна.

Comment: выведите `console.log(url)`. Смотрите какой URL формируется, может там id не передается, ..  И.Т.Д

Comment: Так я для этого и получал ID через _id, после чего через конкатенацию добавляю к url

Comment: Да ну ясно для чего вы получали ID. Проблема то у вас в том что нету такой страницы которая бы приняла POST запрос. Указывайте верный адрес в url, или если страница существует то приводите ее код

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan до меня видимо не доходит, о чем вы говорите...

Comment: `url : "/comments/" + _id,` Тут вы указываете путь к файлу(action) который должен обработать ваш запрос и вернуть результат.404 говорит о том что путь не верный. Это может быть по нескольким причинам. 1. либо действительно вы указали неверный адрес , 2. Либо адрес существует, и по каким то причинам PHP возвращает такой результат.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan адрес точно существует, потому что при переходе на него я точно вижу комментарий с нужным id и нужными остальными данными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблема заключалась в совсем мелких вещах, и точно не id

во первых по клику - я передавал только ID элемента, поэтому :

```
ng-click="addReplay(item.id)"
```

я заменил на : `ng-click="addReplay(item)"`
после чего заменил модель на `ng-model="item.children.content"`

Ну и в самом js файле я переделал параметры и убрал конкатенацию

```
params : {
            'parent' : _id.id,
            'content' : _id.children.content
        }
```

вот и все, спасибо всем за помощь.